# Generating URLs according to the search engine query

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines

What is the name of following technique:

When you search a multi word keyword, for example "download physics book edition 218324", the search engine finds a page from a website with exactly same parameters like:

```
example.com/whatever/download-physics-book-edition-218324
```

Now because this is a very very specific query with a very specific number, it is sure that the page does not actually exist on that website, but it is generated dynamically according to that query. When you click on the above URL, it can lead to the search page of that website where that query has been copied.

What is name of this technique/method? and how is this done?

Comment: There is no technique or method that exist on the web.

Comment: That page would have to exist before the query.   It wouldn't be hard to build a site with a page for every edition of every text book.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a specific name for this "technique" but if I understand correctly this is very much akin to practices which fall outside of Google's guidelines.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721306
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311

What you're looking to do, at least how I understand it, is to programmatically create internal search pages for various search terms that users may enter and to make these pages indexable on Google.

If you actually have content on your website that can answer the query, in your example, if you have a page that allows the user to actually "download physics book edition 218324" then that sounds ok, and what you want to do is to simply surface that content to the user. In which case you're probably better off creating a single category page for "Physics Books" which give users an ability to search your database by edition or author or some other parameter.

Cheers and good luck